# scons not using PATH for ParseConfig

Tags: scons, sdl-2

I have a simple SConstruct file that contains the following:

```
env = Environment()
env.ParseConfig('sdl2-config --cflags')
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
$scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
/bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
```

However, I can run sdl2-config from the same shell:

```
$ sdl2-config --cflags
-I/opt/local/include/SDL2 -D_THREAD_SAFE
$ which sdl2-config
/opt/local/bin/sdl2-config
```

Is there something special I need to do to make scons use my PATH?
I'm on MacOS 10.9.5, using scons 2.3.4 installed by MacPorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. SCons does not use the user's path by default. You need to pass the PATH explicitly to the Environment:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
```

See the [SCons FAQ](http://scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.).